# Instance created before method definition

Tags: ruby

Why does `a` created before `class_eval` in the code have access to `world`?

```
class Hello; end

a = Hello.new

Hello.class_eval {def world; puts "Hi" end}

b = Hello.new

a.world #=> "Hi"
b.world #=> "Hi"
```

How does `class_eval` work behind the scenes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes in ruby are open. As `Hello` was given with a new method, method dispatch on all instances got updated with this. If you want to extend `a` only, call `class_eval` on `a`’s eigenclass:

```
class Hello; end

a = Hello.new

class << a; def world; puts "Hi" end end
# or, the equivalent: 
# a.singleton_class.class_eval { def world; puts "Hi" end }

b = Hello.new

a.world #⇒ "Hi"
b.world #⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `world' for #<Hello>
```

Comment: You don't need `class_eval{` ... `}`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `a` created before `class_eval` in the code have access to `world`?

It doesn't. Methods are stored in modules, not the instances. (Well, modules are instances of `Module`, but that's irrelevant here.) All `a` knows is that it's an instance of `Hello`, i.e. its `class` pointer points to `Hello` (again, technically that's not true, its `class` pointer points to its singleton class and its singleton class's `superclass` pointer points to `Hello`, but that is also irrelevant here). When `a` gets sent the `world` message it checks its class, `Hello`, for a `world` method, and sure enough, there is one because it was added before the message was sent, so it executes it.

> How does `class_eval` work behind the scenes?

This has nothing to do with `class_eval`, it would work exactly the same way without metaprogramming. `class_eval` is a red herring here:

```
class Hello; end

a = Hello.new

class Hello; def world; puts "Hi" end end

b = Hello.new

a.world # "Hi"
b.world # "Hi"
```